# How to use the code to change the seleted view controller of managed by a UITabbar Controller?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I would like to change the deleted view controller by using code, without tapping the tab bar. Does anyone know how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I just realize that the it is easy to change the tab bar's selected index by setting the selected index.